# Finding the default project settings file

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to write a plugin for 3ds max, I went through the entire sdk installation process to the letter as described in the help files.

The problem I'm facing though is intellisence complaining about an invalid macro definition

"IntelliSense: command-line error: invalid macro definition:_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES_COUNT =1"

I found the definition in project settigs -> c/c++ -> preprocessor definitions as inherited from parent or project default.

I tried disabling the inherited definitions and re-entered them, this time without the space between the name and the = and all works fine so I'm guessing its a typo on their part?

Anyway, I want to change the default project or whatever to not repeat it every time i start a new project. The project is created with a wizard which required me to copy over some files to appear and after which I had to enter the sdk path.

The files I copied are plain text with some fancy extensions and not much in them so I'm guessing the defaults are described in the sdk directory.. somewhere. Does anybody know what kind of a file I'm looking for?

EDIT: I found a file called root.vcxproj_template and it has a section for preprocessor definitions but all it contains is

```
<PreprocessorDefinitions>_USRDLL;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
```

and no mention of the broken one

EDIT2: in another part of the file there was a path to a property sheet (maxsdk\ProjectSettings\propertySheets\3dsmax.common.tools.settings) which included the faulty definition. I fixed it an no more complaints from VS.

Answer (score 0):

_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES_COUNT = 1 means that compiler should replace all old C run-time routines such as **sprintf**, **strcpy**, **strtok** with new versions such as **strprintf_s**, **strcpy_s**, **strtok_s** and similar. It goes in pair with following definition _CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES  = 1.

More you can find here: (MSDN) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175759.aspx. However I tried to use this but without success. It says that you can use this only for statically allocated buffers like **char buffer[32]**, but compilers was still complaining bout unsecure **strcpy**.